# Do all terms $n$ of OEIS sequence A228059 have a $p$ with exponent $1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Do all terms $n$ of OEIS sequence [A228059](http://oeis.org/A228059) have a $p$ with exponent $1$?

**OEIS sequence A228059:  Odd numbers of the form $p^{1+4k}{r^2}$, where $p$ is prime of the form $1+4m$, $r > 1$, and $\gcd(p,r) = 1$ that are closer to being perfect than previous terms.**

Here are the first couple of terms:
$$45 = 5\cdot{3^2}$$
$$405 = 5\cdot{3^4}$$
$$2205 = 5\cdot(3\cdot7)^2$$
$$26325 = 13\cdot({3^2}\cdot5)^2$$
$$236925 = 13\cdot({3^3}\cdot5)^2$$
$$1380825 = 17\cdot(3\cdot5\cdot19)^2$$
$$1660725 = 61\cdot(3\cdot5\cdot11)^2$$
$$35698725 = 61\cdot({3^2}\cdot5\cdot17)^2$$
$$3138290325 = 53\cdot({3^4}\cdot5\cdot19)^2$$

**UPDATE - July 05 2017 (7:30 PM - Manila time):**  I am currently running the Mathematica code referenced in the OEIS sequence to compute more terms past $3138290325$.

**UPDATE - July 06 2017 (1:00 AM - Manila time):**  The Mathematica code is still running and is currently at $35698725$.  It has not displayed $3138290325$ yet.

Comment: Given the information on the OEIS page, it looks like an open problem if we always will have $k = 0$ or not...

Comment: @Ahmad, can you link to the question(s) I asked before, *in disguise* to use your term, that is the same as the present question?

Comment: @DirkLiebhold, please note that the papers listed on the OEIS page are *independent* of sequence [A228059](http://oeis.org/A228059).

Comment: I wasn't referring to the paper, but rather the sentence "Coincidently, the first 9 numbers in this sequence have exponent 1.". If someone already worked out that all terms have exponent 1, not just the first 9 ones, then why didn't he post it there?

Comment: Sorry, not the same but related. My mistake.

Comment: I have added the 10th term (as communicated by T. D. Noe), and Giovanni Resta has computed the 11th to 37th terms of OEIS sequence A228059.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the first $37$ terms:

$$45 = 5\cdot{3^2}$$
$$405 = 5\cdot{3^4}$$
$$2205 = 5\cdot(3\cdot7)^2$$
$$26325 = 13\cdot({3^2}\cdot5)^2$$
$$236925 = 13\cdot({3^3}\cdot5)^2$$
$$1380825 = 17\cdot(3\cdot5\cdot19)^2$$
$$1660725 = 61\cdot(3\cdot5\cdot11)^2$$
$$35698725 = 61\cdot({3^2}\cdot5\cdot17)^2$$
$$3138290325 = 53\cdot({3^4}\cdot5\cdot19)^2$$
$$29891138805 = {5}\cdot({3^2}\cdot{{11}^2}\cdot{71})^2$$
$$73846750725 = {509}\cdot({3}\cdot{5}\cdot{11}\cdot{73})^2$$
$$194401220013 = {21557}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
$$194509436121 = {21569}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
$$194581580193 = {21577}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
$$194689796301 = {21589}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
$$194798012409 = {21601}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
$$194906228517 = {21613}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
$$194942300553 = {21617}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
$$195230876841 = {21649}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
$$195339092949 = {21661}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
$$195447309057 = {21673}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
$$195699813309 = {21701}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
$$195808029417 = {21713}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
$$196024461633 = {21737}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
$$196204821813 = {21757}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
$$196349109957 = {21773}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
$$196745902353 = {21817}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
$$196781974389 = {21821}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
$$196962334569 = {21841}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
$$197323054929 = {21881}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
$$197431271037 = {21893}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
$$197755919361 = {21929}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
$$197828063433 = {21937}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
$$198044495649 = {21961}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
$$198188783793 = {21977}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
$$198369143973 = {21997}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
$$198513432117 = {22013}\cdot({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$

(I used [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com) for computing the prime factorizations of the $11$th to $37$th terms.)  Note that each of the first $37$ terms of OEIS sequence A228059 have a $p$ with exponent $1$.

Furthermore, note that the *non-Euler part value* ($n^2$) of
$$({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13})^2$$
is [deficient-perfect](http://oeis.org/A271816), and that this condition is [known to be equivalent](http://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-23/NNTDM-23-2-012-020.pdf) to the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli conjecture that $s=1$, if $q^s n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special/Euler prime $q$.

Lastly, by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2871001/28816), it is known that the Descartes spoof
$$\mathscr{D} = {3^2}\cdot{7^2}\cdot{{11}^2}\cdot{{13}^2}\cdot{22021} = 198585576189$$
is not a member of OEIS sequence [A228059](http://oeis.org/A228059).