# Is $198585576189$ a member of OEIS sequence A228059?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, mathematica, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

I currently do not have enough computing power, so please pardon me for my question, which occurred just recently to me.

So here it goes:

> Is the Descartes spoof 
>   $$\mathscr{D} = {3^2}\cdot{7^2}\cdot{{11}^2}\cdot{{13}^2}\cdot{22021} = 198585576189$$
>   a member of OEIS sequence [A228059](http://oeis.org/A228059)?

There is an existing Mathematica code in the OEIS hyperlink to test this.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that $22021 = {{19}^2}\cdot{61}$,

Comment: Looking at the Mathematica code, I suppose that it will take a **long** time to generate  the 10th, 11th, ... terms.

Comment: Yes, essentially that is the problem, @ClaudeLeibovici.  Note that the Descartes spoof *might* be the 10th or 11th term.  Who knows?  =)

Comment: As you say, who knows ?

Comment: I have just also posted a closely related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2870886).

Comment: Please refer to the [following answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2891869/28816) to a closely related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question is *NO*, since the abundancy index $I(x):=\sigma(x)/x$ (where $\sigma(x)$ is the sum of the divisors of $x \in \mathbb{N}$) of the first $9$ terms of OEIS sequence A228059 are:

$$I(45) = \frac{26}{15} \approx 1.73333$$
[WolframAlpha computation here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DivisorSigma%5B1,45%5D%2F45)
$$I(405) = \frac{242}{135} \approx 1.79259$$
[WolframAlpha computation here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DivisorSigma%5B1,405%5D%2F405)
$$I(2205) = \frac{494}{245} \approx 2.01633$$
[WolframAlpha computation here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DivisorSigma%5B1,2205%5D%2F2205)
$$I(26325) = \frac{52514}{26325} \approx 1.99483$$
[WolframAlpha computation here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DivisorSigma%5B1,26325%5D%2F26325)
$$I(236925) = \frac{474362}{236925} \approx 2.00216$$
[WolframAlpha computation here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DivisorSigma%5B1,236925%5D%2F236925)
$$I(1380825) = \frac{307086}{153425} \approx 2.00154$$
[WolframAlpha computation here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DivisorSigma%5B1,1380825%5D%2F1380825)
$$I(1660725) = \frac{3323138}{1660725} \approx 2.00102$$
[WolframAlpha computation here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DivisorSigma%5B1,1660725%5D%2F1660725)
$$I(35698725) = \frac{71396534}{35698725} \approx 1.99997$$
[WolframAlpha computation here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DivisorSigma%5B1,35698725%5D%2F35698725)
$$I(3138290325) = \frac{77488034}{38744325} \approx 1.99998$$
[WolframAlpha computation here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DivisorSigma%5B1,3138290325%5D%2F3138290325)

Notice that, by the definition of OEIS sequence A228059, $|I(x_i)-2|$ must be a (strictly?) decreasing sequence.

Therefore, since
$$I(198585576189) = \frac{23622}{11011} \approx 2.14531,$$
it follows that the Descartes spoof
$$\mathscr{D} = 198585576189$$
is not a member of OEIS sequence A228059.

**Added August 15 2018**

In an e-mail correspondence, Tony D. Noe (author of OEIS sequence A228059) says that "(he) found the next term for this sequence: $29891138805 = {5}\cdot({3^2}\cdot{{11}^2}\cdot{71})^2$, (and that) (i)t took $5$ days on a fairly fast Mac."

Comment: Please refer to the [following answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2891869/28816) to a closely related question.